# Anylogic Foor Loop adding agents through enter block

Tags: anylogic, agent, enter

I want to add a number(parameter) of agents (resources) through a cyclic event from a database (scans). I do not use an Exit Block before.
It all works for 1 cycle then I get a NullPointerExeption error.
Maybe some of you can help.. searched all questions and could not find an answer.

This is what I tried so far..

```
parameter = (int) selectFrom(scans)
    .where(scans.al_id.gt(id))
    .firstResult(scans.scans);
    
for(int i=0; i<parameter; i++){
    Ressource ressource = new Ressource ();
    enter.take(ressource); 
};

id++;
```

Answer (score 0):

first create a population of agents called ressources,

with that done, instead of using new Ressource();

you can do add `add_ressources();`

Neverhteless your null point exception might be unrelated to this.. but when you create agents using new Ressource();
you should add this line:

```
ressource.createAndStart(this);
```

another option is to use a source and do `source.inject(parameter);`